# Give an example of function continuous for $x \in (a, b)$ and not differentiable in $a < x_{1} <\dots < x_{n} < b $, but differentiable in intervals.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Give an example of a function continuous for x $\in (a, b)$ and not differentiable
> in $a < x_{1}< \dots < x_{n} < b $, but differentiable
> in intervals $(a, x_{1}), (x_{n}, b), (x_{i}, x_{i+1})$ for $i = 1,
>  \ldots, n-1 $

My idea:

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{x-a}{x_{1}-a} & x \in  [a,x_{1}] \\
-\frac{(x-x_{n-1})}{(x_{n}-x_{n-1})} + 1  &  x \in  [x_{n-1}, x_{n}] \text{ and  n odd} \\
\frac{x-x_{n-1}}{x_{n}-x_{n-1}}  & x \in  [x_{n-1}, x_{n}]\text{ and n even }\\
\frac{x-x_{n}}{x_{n}-b} & x \in [x_{n},b]
\end{cases}
$$

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2BLn.png]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: In the second and third case of the function definition, $n$ should be some other index, for example $j$, $2 \le j \le n$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your idea is sound, but here is a function that doesn't rely on the parity of $n$. Let $[l(x),u(x)]$ be the one interval stated in the question that an argument $x\not\in\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ lies in. Then
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
(x-l(x))(x-u(x))&x\not\in\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}\\
0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Can you develop this sentence? " Let $l(x),u(x)$ be the one interval stated in the question that an argument.."

Comment: @MartinInf1n1ty If $a<x<x_1$ and $l(x)=a$ and $u(x)=x_1$, and so on.

Comment: Many Thanks @Parcly Taxel

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Are you sure that your $f$ is continuous for $x\in (a,b)$?

Comment: @qerty149: The function *is* continuous. Why do you think that the solution is wrong?

Comment: if $l(x)$ is an interval, what does $x-l(x)$ mean? do you shift an interval by displacement $x$?

Comment: @Zion: $l(x)$ and $u(x)$ are lower and upper bound of the interval  that $x$ lies in. In other words, if $x_k \le x \le x_{k+1}$ then $f(x) = (x-x_k)(x-x_{k+1}$. That is a parabola which is zero at the endpoints.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: Perhaps write “Let $[l(x),u(x)]$ be the one interval ...” for clarification? Just a suggestion.

Comment: @MartinR done..

Answer (score 7):

A simple example is the function $f:(a, b) \to \Bbb R$ defined as
$$
 f(x) = \prod_{j=1}^n |x -x_j| \, .
$$

- $f$ is continuous as a product of continuous functions.
- $f$ is differentiable in $(a, b) \setminus \{ x_1, \ldots, x_n \} $ because each factor is differentiable there.
- $f$ is *not* differentiable at each point $x_k$, $k = 1, \ldots, n$.

For the last statement note that
$$
 \lim_{x \to x_k^-} \frac{f(x)-f(x_k)}{x-x_k} = - \prod_{j\ne k} |x_k -x_j|
$$
and
$$
 \lim_{x \to x_k^+} \frac{f(x)-f(x_k)}{x-x_k} = + \prod_{j\ne k} |x_k -x_j|
$$
and the left and right limit are different because the product on the right is not zero.

*Example:* $(a, b) = (0, 5)$, $(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (1, 2, 4)$.

[image]

The square root of $f$
$$
 g(x) = \prod_{j=1}^n \sqrt{|x -x_j|} 
$$
also has the desired properties, and does not even have (finite) one-sided derivatives at the points $x_k$:

[image]

For a “more chaotic” behaviour at the $x_k$ we can define $h:(a, b) \to \Bbb R$ as
$$
 h(x) = \prod_{j=1}^n \phi(x -x_j) 
$$
where $\phi: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ has the following properties:

- $\phi$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$.
- $\phi(0) = 0$, $\phi(x) \ne 0$ for $x \ne 0$.
- $\phi$ is differentiable on $\Bbb R \setminus \{ 0 \}$.
- $\phi$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Example with with $\phi(x) = x \cdot (\sin(10/x)+2)$ for $x \ne 0$, $\phi(0) = 0$:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

We can construct a simple function,which is a series of upper half circles, as shown in the above plot, with $x_0=a, x_{n+1}=b$.

For each upper half circle defined on the interval $[x_k, x_{k+1}]$, the coordinate for each center $O_k$ is $\displaystyle (\frac{x_k+x_{k+1}}{2}, 0)$, with radius $r_k=\frac{x_{k+1}-x_k}{2}$

So we get the function as:

$$f(x)=\sqrt{\left(\frac{x_{k+1}-x_k}{2}\right)^2-\left(x-\frac{x_k+x_{k+1}}{2}\right)^2},~~~~~~x\in [x_k, x_{k+1}]$$